# Length of Binary as Base 10 [OEIS A242347]

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

Computers like binary. Humans like base 10. Assuming users are humans, why not find the best of both worlds?
Your task is to find the first `n` terms in the sequence [A008559](https://oeis.org/A008559) where each term is the binary representation of the previous number interpreted as a base 10 number.

### Input

An integer greater than 0. Note that the first value of A008559 is 2.

### Output

Just to make it a little more readable, the output should be the number of digits in the Nth term of A008559, which is [A242347](https://oeis.org/A242347).
Invalid inputs can output whatever, standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules apply.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest bytecount wins, no standard loopholes etc...

### Test Cases

```
2 -> [1,2]
5 -> [1,2,4,10,31]
10 -> [1,2,4,10,31,100,330,1093,3628,12049]
20 -> [1,2,4,10,31,100,330,1093,3628,12049,40023,132951,441651,1467130,4873698,16190071,53782249,178660761,593498199,1971558339]
```

Comment: I had the output be the length of the number because this blows up very very quickly

Comment: Is outputting the infinite sequence starting from 2 (i.e. \$2, 4, 10, 31, 100, 330, ...\$) ok?

Comment: Yes, and the sequence technically has 2 as the first term

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `l`, <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
2?(ΠE
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJsIiwiIiwiMj8ozqBFIiwiIiwiMTIiXQ==)

Outputs nth term

### Explained

```
2?(ΠE
2      # Push 2 to the stack
 ?(    # Input times:
   ΠE  #   push int(binary representation of top of stack)
       # the `l` flag pushes the length of the top of the stack
```

### Old 7 byter, outputs infinite sequence

```
2‡ΠEḞvL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiMuKAoc6gReG4nnZMIiwiIiwiMTIiXQ==)

### Explained

```
2‡ΠEḞẎvL
2‡  Ḟ    # an infinite generator that gets its next term by:
  ΠE     #   converting its previous term to binary and casting to int   
      vL # lengths of every item
```

Comment: https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiMuKAoc6gReG4nuG6jnZMIiwiIiwiMTIiXQ==

Comment: https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiMuKAoc6gReG4nnZMIiwiIiwiMTIiXQ== new link

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>38</s> <s>33</s> 25 bytes

```ruby
a=2;loop{p /$/=~a="%b"%a}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWOxNtjaxz8vMLqgsU9FX0besSbZVUk5RUE2sh8lBlMOUA)
Outputs the sequence indefinitely starting from 2.

Thanks for a whopping -13 bytes from a collective effort by south and Dingus.

Comment: [33 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWNxUL6nQTbY2sc_LzC6oLFPRV9G3rEm2VVJOUVBP1SvLjM2shCqHqYfoA)

Comment: It looks like you don't need `.to_i`, and if you start the sequence from 2 (which OP allowed in the comments) you can remove the initial `p~-`.

Comment: Good catch, that brings it down to 25 `a=2;loop{p /$/=~a="%b"%a}`. I thought to try it without `#to_i`, but I guess I didn't idk.

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>9</s> 9 bytes

```
¡o§,ḋLd;2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qG2iocGjpsb/hxbmH1qu83BHt0@KtdH//wA)

Outputs the infinite sequence.

---

The previous version (also 9 bytes when outputting the infinite sequence) was
`moLd¡odḋ2`, but I've cleaned this up at the [request of lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253857/length-of-binary-as-base-10-oeis-a242347/253861#comment563846_253861), who considered it too odd due to the moLd in it.

```
         2 # starting with 2
     ¡     # construct an infinite sequence
      o    # by repeatedly applying 2 functions:
        ḋ  #   convert to binary digits
       d   #   convert from base-10 digits
 m         # now map over this infinite list
  o        # using 2 functions:
   L       #   length of
    d      #   base-10 digits
```

Comment: this seems like a very odḋ answer :p (especially given that it has moLd on it - get that answer cleaned!)

Comment: @lyxal - Ok, cleaned now.

Comment: Thank goodness - last thing we need is spoiled code golf answers making a stench :p

Comment: @lyxal that, the moLd comment, made my day today.

Answer (score 5):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$8\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 6.585 bytes

```
eLG2'_Ob
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJlTEcyJ19PYiIsIiJd)

Port of Vyxal

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 14 bytes

```
{#$x(10/2\)/2}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pWVqnQMDTQN4rR1Deq5eJKUzfUVjQGAEsCBXk=)

Outputs the nth element.

Unfortunately, this can only do the first 3 elements because it's written in C, so overflow happens very quickly.

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 35 bytes

```factor
2 [ >bin dup length . dec> t ] loop
```

Prints the infinite sequence starting with 2. Times out on TIO, but here's a screenshot using the debugger to step through some of the starting iterations:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Sequences](https://github.com/nayakrujul/sequences), \$9 \log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 7.4 bytes

```
2HE2hBnHz
```

#### Explanation

```js
2HE2hBnHz
  E        // Infinite sequence
2H         // Starting with 2
           // For each term:
   2hB     //   Convert to binary
      n    //   Interpret as integer
       H   //   And use this as the next term
        z  //   Get the length and output implicitly
```

Comment: Suggested mathjax fix: `\$9 log_{256}(96) ≈ 7.4\$` to `\$9 \log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 7.4`

Comment: why does this have the same fractional byte values as fig?

Comment: @Pacmanboss256 - it uses the same character set as Fig (printable ASCII characters)

Comment: @TheThonnu - it looks from the 'sequences' 'list of commands' page that there are only 57 commands.  After adding the decimal digits, you could presumably decide to score yourself as 9 log256(67) ≈ 6.82435 bytes...  although I notice that most conventional programming languages that also only use printable ASCII values + newlines don't seem very keen to adopt this scoring strategy...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen - the other characters, even if they are not commands, could be used in strings, so I don't want to rule out that possibility. (For example, not including `w` would make sequences incapable of using the string "Hello world".)

Comment: @TheThonnu - Ah, ok.  I suppose that 'sequences' also has some kind of quotation system (the ```"``` character?) that isn't in the 'list of commands', then...  It would be interesting to wonder whether encoding strings in base-67 would come-out shorter, if you're going down the fractional-byte-count road (since your final log256 could be smaller)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen yes, strings in sequences start and end with `"`. I think I'll stick with base-96 though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>56 47</s> 40 bytes

- -9 thanks to friddo.
- -7 thanks to loopy walt.

Outputs the infinite sequence, starting from 2. (Note: [apparently this is fine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253857/length-of-binary-as-base-10-oeis-a242347/253863#comment563886_253863))

```python
i=2
while i:=f"{int(i):b}":print(len(i))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU2vzNyC_KISheLKYq78gqLMvBJbMMmVkpqmAGZpVGhacSlkpilU2BkagIEVULFeakVmiYaBJpdCPkzV0tKSNF2LmxqZtkZc5RmZOakKmVa2aUrVINlMTaukWiUriNKc1DygAFT9AigFpQE)

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>66</s> 59 bytes

- -7 thanks to loopy walt.

Suggested by friddo. Returns the first n terms.

```python
lambda n,i=2:[1]+[len(i:=f"{int(i):b}")for _ in range(1,n)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3rXMSc5NSEhXydDJtjayiDWO1o3NS8zQyrWzTlKoz80o0MjWtkmqVNNPyixTiFTLzFIoS89JTNQx18jRjoUbogOQSkeUUDA01rbgUCopABiTqKKjr2qnrKKRpJGpqQvQsWAChAQ)

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>74</s> 69 bytes

- -5 thanks to loopy walt.

Returns the n<sup>th</sup> term.

```python
lambda n,i=2:len((['1']+[(i:=f"{int(i):b}")for _ in range(n-1)])[-1])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3XXMSc5NSEhXydDJtjaxyUvM0NKLVDdVjtaM1Mq1s05SqM_NKNDI1rZJqlTTT8osU4hUy8xSKEvPSUzXydA01YzWjdQ1jNaGG6YBUJCJUGOooGBpqWnEpFBSBjEnUUVDXtVPXUUjTSNSE6lmwAEIDAA)

Comment: [66 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3nXISc5NSEhXydDJtjayiDWO1o3NS8zSKS4o0Mq1sM_NKNJIy8zQyNaONrGI1NTXT8osU4hUy8xSKEvPSUzUMdfI0Y6Em6YDkEpHlFAwNNa24FAqKQMYk6iio69qp6yikaSRqakL0LFgAoQE)

Comment: the screenshot makes it look as if you've forgotten the '1' at the beginning...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen - yes, that solution misses the initial '1'. It says "starting from 2" just above it.

Comment: Ah yes, but probably worth querying whether that's Ok.  My feeling is that leaving-out the first element of a sequence shouldn't be valid...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen - thanks. I've added a [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253857/length-of-binary-as-base-10-oeis-a242347/253863?noredirect=1#comment563873_253857) asking the OP if that's ok.

Comment: But, in any case my other two answers still work.

Comment: Yes, the others are fine, and presumably you could just add ```print(1)``` to the start of the problem one (for +9 bytes)...

Comment: I am guessing for the infinite sequence, that it being a function is optional. Scratch the definition for [47 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY39TNtjbjKMzJzUhUMrQqKMvNKNHJS8zSKS4o0Mq1sQdykzDyNTM1oI6tYTSCAaIPqhpkCAA)

Comment: youre supposed to start from 2 otherwise you just get  [1,1,1...

Comment: @Pacmanboss256 - [A008559](https://oeis.org/A008559) starts from 2. This one ([A242347](https://oeis.org/A242347)) starts from 1, and goes \$[1, 2, 4, 10, 31, 100, ...]\$.

Comment: @pacmanboss - you're confusing the two sequences: A008559 must start from 2, but, as a result, A242347 starts from 1, although I see that you've allowed it to start at the second term for this challenge.  Edit: as The Thonnu also wrote while I was typing...

Comment: either way is fine, its sort of a convoluted question

Comment: [40](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU2vzNyC_KISheLKYq78gqLMvBJbMMmVkpqmAGZpVGhacSlkpilU2BkagIEVULFeakVmiYaBJpdCPkzV0tKSNF2LmxqZtkZc5RmZOakKmVa2aUrVINlMTaukWiUriNKc1DygAFT9AigFpQE) mostly by avoiding the redundant int str round trip.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 67 bytes

```c
q;b;v;f(n){for(v=2;n--;v=q)for(b=q=0;v;v/=2)q+=v%2*exp10(b++);q=b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDZbsIwEHznK1aRkBKSCB@5LNd9qfoVhQdiHIoKgRxNUVF@vek6HC2WvN6ZnVl5V4cbrYehkrnsZOGW3rk41G6nmCzDUHaq8izOVaUICrq5Yl7lq27KZuZ0pMTNfd@TlcplP2zLFvarbel6cJ4AHkugyujWrN@WoODMAogCoCQATnsJ8zlYZCEnNhMc04RlmDMSCVQTwpCjnImYIoxoYl8aJSm1lihLeSKsPqGCkBRrMU8zxqyZplmSkDSxpOCRyKiwrEhpHGeci16O39SHsmlBv6/qGUajP0x9@a2zOL2yxUm84I2dAP5j7lzduB5w7aTbcm1OaCPymj5Bs/02h8K97cCD@Y2a3TkJvj/qb1u7ba7FXpdGPlD5UGqwVLit98gaZO/rHp3LP8GxRknhOtM1hM@AcdosSpypDaAJ7mM3SpnltW0/xtq0n3WJQ0364UcXu9WmGcKvIdztfwE)

Inputs \$1\$-based \$n\$.
Returns the \$n^{\text{th}}\$ element starting with \$a(1) = 2\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>75</s> 63 bytes

```hs
g 2
g x=length(show$f x):g(f x)
f 0=0
f n=f(div n 2)*10+mod n 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBbsIwEEX3nGIWXQTqSjMex/ZU8hF6AyQUAXGiJCYiqOX0NcPmv6@n/4dum67zXKd0rBnsLsMzzdeSH0OzDbe/jx6e@@/cvLHrARNqltQ3l/EXCtj9gfBzuV3evS7dWCDB0q0/J1jvY3nAVK1xhtAwaSoYlcKGvY2GLDoxDtGyIbbSknGOvIKcD6RbFwN70aUnQQxkWg7RWn1RiN5j8KqEnUQSdRKobSOz/J/7uctb/Tqv6ws)

- Thanks to @Sʨɠɠan for saving 2 Bytes

*f n* returns a (decimal binary, length) tuple

Comment: You can save two bytes by just doing `f x` twice: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBbsIwEEX3nGIWXQTqSjMex/ZU8hF6AyQUAXGiJCYiqOX0NcPmv6@n/4dum67zXKd0rBnsLsMzzdeSH0OzDbe/jx6e@@/cvLHrARNqltQ3l/EXCtj9gfBzuV3evS7dWCDB0q0/J1jvY3nAVK1xhtAwaSoYlcKGvY2GLDoxDtGyIbbSknGOvIKcD6RbFwN70aUnQQxkWg7RWn1RiN5j8KqEnUQSdRKobSOz/J/7uctb/Tqv6ws "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
L.BsbmlyF2
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=L.BsbmlyF2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A5%0A10&debug=0)

Prints the first \$n\$ terms.

The `m` can be omitted to instead print \$a(n)\$, where \$a(0)=2\$.

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38soN8dWz6nY6/9/QwMA) if you're okay with omitting the first term

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 19 bytes

```apl
{≢⍕(10⊥2∘⊥⍣¯1)⍣⍵⊢2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/P@1R24TqR52LHvVO1TA0eNS11OhRxwwg9ah38aH1hppA6lHv1kddi4xq/z/qmwpUnHZohaGCkYKxgomC6X8A)

Due to limits, this can also only output the first 5 elements.

This works in Dyalog too, but can only output the first 3 elements there.

Answer (score 3):

## PARI/GP 55 bytes

```
f(n)=k=2;d=digits;while(n--,k=fromdigits(d(k,2)));#d(k)
```

Stack of 8 GBytes overflows for n=18.

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), <s>16</s> 30 bytes

```
map *.chars,(2,+*.base(2)...*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1up4FCsYPs/N7FAQUsvOSOxqFhHw0hHW0svKbE4VcNIU09PT0vzv7VCcSJIZXScWex/AA)

An expression for the lazy, infinite sequence of numbers.

Comment: The challenge asks you to output the length, not the number itself

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan Huh...dunno how I missed that.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 18 bytes

```
[:#@":10x&(#.#:)&2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxKdpK2UHJytCgQk1DWU_ZSlPNCCKxS5MrNTkjXyFNQU3PDqjLUMFIwVjBRMFUwQyiYMECCA0A)

-2 thanks to Jonah!

Comment: Nice, I will give your bounty back!  Couple notes: you need 10x or you'll get wrong answers for 5 and above.  Note sure if 0 indexing like this uses is allowed here, but assuming it is here's a tacit version for 18: `[:#@":10x&(#.#:)&2`

Comment: Thanks! What does `x` mean? Is it some kind of bigint thing?

Comment: Exactly.  It stands for "eXtended precision".  10x is a way to write it as a literal.  You could also do `x:10` to convert using the verb `x:`

Comment: Ah, nice. I searched for J bigints but didn't find anything. It's a pain to use google with J because it doesn't go well with only one letter. (Why does it have to be called J?) I usually just search `jsoftware`, but that narrows it down a little. Also, the names of verbs in the vocabulary are very vague often.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
‘ḊḌB$\Ẉ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer, \$n\$, and yields a list of the first \$n\$ terms.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4yHO7oe7uhxUol5uKvj////hgYA)**

#### How?

Performs each conversion step in the opposite order as it avoids the need to get lists again at the end.

Uses a reduce that only uses the left item at each step, starting with a list of length \$n\$ that starts with a \$2\$ as it saves a byte over collecting up \$n-1\$ times starting with a \$2\$.

```
‘ḊḌB$\Ẉ - Link: integer, n
‘       - increment (n) -> n+1
 Ḋ      - dequeue ([1..n+1]) -> [2..n+1]
     \  - reduce by:
    $   -   last two links as a monad - i.e. f(left):
 Ḍ      -     convert from decimal e.g. 2 -> 2     or [1,0,1,0] -> 1010
  B     -     convert to binary    e.g. 2 -> [1,0] or 1010 -> [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]
      Ẉ - length of each
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 54 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [@Sʨɠɠan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/s%ca%a8%c9%a0%c9%a0an)*

Prints the sequence indefinitely, starting at \$2\$ (as now allowed by the OP).

```javascript
for(n=2;;console.log(n.length))n=BigInt(n).toString(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDAXQ67SDDKzExc3ZExDEiiG/BhqvX9978pdnGe21BXpW90sHYY0pFcXUXkNXIYReIXYzY92a7DACB9PDRoNQZPcf)

Comment: 54 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDAXQ67SDDKzExc3ZExDEiiG/BhqvX9978pdnGe21BXpW90sHYY0pFcXUXkNXIYReIXYzY92a7DACB9PDRoNQZPcf "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: Also you can remove those random trailing semicolons

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan Thank you! (And yeah, the trailing semicolons were very random indeed. I guess I was thinking in C for a second.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 7.5 bytes (15 nibbles)

```
.`.2`@~``@$,`p
```

```
   2            # start with 2
 `.             # iterate while unique:
       ``@$     #   convert to bits
    `@~         #   and convert to base 10
.               # now, map over this infinite list
           ,    #   get lengths of
            `p  #   string representations
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 21 bytes

```
"2""2X>b >S"itr"len"map
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Returns an infinite list.

For testing purposes (use `-i` flag if running locally):

```
; 10tk >A
"2""2X>b >S"itr"len"map
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
"2" ( 2X>b >S ) itr \len map
```

- `"2" ( ... ) itr` generate infinite list starting from 2...

  - `2X>b` to binary
  - `>S` to string
- `\len map` get lengths of each element

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
≔2θＦＮ«⟦ＩＬθ⟧≔⍘Ｉθ²θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU9DyUhJR6FQ05orLb9IQcMzr6C0xK80Nym1SENTU6GaizOgKDOvRCPaObG4RMMnNS@9JEOjUFMzFqiBE2qCU2JxanAJUFm6BlhVoaaOgpEmxNDa//9N/@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. As we are outputting A242347, which starts with `1`, so does this version. Explanation:

```
≔2θ
```

Start with `2`.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
⟦ＩＬθ⟧
```

Output its length on its own line.

```
≔⍘Ｉθ²θ
```

Cast it to decimal, then convert it to binary as a string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 45 bytes

```
.+
$*:2
{`:\d+
$*B
+`(B+)\1
$1A
AB
B
}T`L`d
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0XLyoirOsEqJgXEduLSTtBw0taMMeRSMXTkcnTicuKqDUnwSUjh0vv/34DLkMuIyxgA) Outputs the 0-indexed `n`th term. Link includes test cases for `0` to `3` as higher values are too slow. Explanation:

```
.+
$*:2
```

Convert the input to unary as a number of `:`s and suffix a `2` for the zeroth value.

```
{`
}`
```

Repeat until the nth value has been found.

```
:\d+
$*B
```

If more terms are needed then convert the current value into unary as a number of `B`s.

```
+`(B+)\1
$1A
AB
B
```

If there are any `B`s then convert them to binary using `B` for `1` and `A` for `0`. This is done separately to avoid corrupting the final value.

```
T`@=`d
```

Convert the "binary" to normal digits.

```
.
```

Count the number of digits in the final value.

A008559 can be obtained at a saving of 3 bytes by deleting the last line and removing the `}`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

```
Y2LaP#TB:y
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJZMkxhUCNUQjp5IiwiIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==)

Prints the first `a` terms in the sequence starting with 2, where `a` is the argument input.

```
Y2LaP#TB:y      ; a = input
Y2              ; Set y = 2
  La            ; Loop the following code "a" times...
    P#          ; Print the length of...
      TB:y      ; y treated as a decimal number converted to a binary string
                  and set y to that value
```

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 9 bytes

```
Lb$
=2:JZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/3ydJhcvWyMor6v9/AA)

Prints the entirely sequence infinitely starting with `1,2,4,10,31,100,330,...`

### Explanation

**First line**

```
       implicit : output the nth term if input is provided, or all terms in the sequence if no input provided
       each term in the sequence equals
L                                       length (                       )
 b                                               second line (       )
  $                                                            index
```

**Second line**

```
=2     first term in sequence is 2
  :    output the nth term in the sequence
       each term in the sequence equals
   J                                    base 2 of (                   )
    Z                                               the previous term
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Infinite sequence starting at `2`:

```
Tλb}€g
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5NzupNpHTWvS//8HAA)

Could be the infinite sequence starting at `1` by replacing `T` with `2`: `2λb}€g` - [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6NzupNpHTWvS//8HAA).

Outputting the \$n^{th}\$ term is 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) as well with either `2λèb}g` ([try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6NzuwyuSatP//zcFAA)) or `2IFb}g` ([try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyNMtqTb9/38DAA));
and outputting the first \$n\$ values is 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) with either `2λ£b}€g` ([try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6NzuQ4uTah81rUn//98UAA)) or `2IFbDg,` ([try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyNMtySVd5/9/UwA)).

**Explanation:**

```python
 λ      # Start a recursive environment,
        # to output the infinite sequence
T       # Starting at a(0)=10
        # Where every following a(n) is calculated as:
        #  (implicitly push the previous term a(n-1))
  b     #  Convert it from a base-10 integer to a binary string
   }€   # After we have the infinite sequence: map over each binary string:
     g  #  Pop and push its length
        # (after which the infinite sequence is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
2æhpià∟
```

Prints the infinite sequence, starting from `1`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/o8LKMgszDCx51zP//HwA)

Outputting the first \$n\$ terms would be 8 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py) instead:

```
2kæhpià;
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/98o@/CyjILMwwusgWwuUy5DAwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
2        # Push a 2
      ∟  # Do-while true (without popping),
 æ       # using 4 characters as inner code-block:
  h      #  Push the length (without popping)
   p     #  Pop and print it with trailing newline
    i    #  Convert the binary-string to a base-10 integer
     à   #  Convert that integer to a binary-string
```

The program for the first \$n\$ terms is pretty similar, except that `k` pushes the input-integer; `æ` acts as a loop that many times instead of the do-while loop; and `;` discards the final binary-string after the loop, which would otherwise have been output implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -Mbigint, 58 bytes

```perl
eval'$_=2;'.'$_=new Math::BigInt($_)->to_bin;'x$_;$_=y///c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHXSXe1shaXQ9E56WWK/gmlmRYWTllpnvmlWioxGvq2pXkxydl5lmrV6jEWwMVVerr6yf//2/IZcRlzGXCZcplxmXOZcFlyWVo8C@/oCQzP6/4v25Bjm9SZnpmXgkA)

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 40 bytes

```
2:2(?v:2%$2,:1%-!
?v00.>lnao>l1)
.>a*+a1
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/#%23S8sszvj/38jKSMO@zMpIVcVIx8pQVVeRy77MwEDPLicvMd8ux1CTS88uUUs70fD/fwA)

"Infinte sequence". Overflows at the 7th number.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 11 bytes

```
)2¤U⟪¤bd⟫⊢l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9nYWlh//8pMsKkVeKfqsKkYmTin6viiqJs//8xMA) or [Try a test suite!](https://tio.run/##AUwAs/9nYWlh//8pMsKkVeKfqsKkYmTin6viiqJs/zpw4oCcIC0@IOKAnXDihpFxClsxIDIgMyA0IDUgNiA3IDggOSAxMCAyMF0g4oaRwqb/)

A sort of copy of the Jelly answer but in Gaia. Times out for >= 12 I think.

### Explained

```
)2¤U⟪¤bd⟫⊢l
)            # Increment the input
 2¤          # Push 2 "under" the incremented input by pushing 2 and then swapping
   U         # Push a range [2, input + 1] to the stack
    ⟪   ⟫⊢   # Reduce that list by:
     ¤b      #   Converting the last item to binary
       d     #   And then to decimal
         l   # Get the length of the result
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 8 bytes

```
2`ĐąŁƥɓł
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fKOHIhCOtRxuPLT05@WjT//8A)

Prints indefinitely.

```
2           push 2
 `     ł    do... while top of stack is truthy
  Đ         Đuplicate
   ą        convert to ąrray of digits
    Łƥ      ƥrint Łength
      ɓ     convert to ɓinary string (implicitly treats output as decimal number)
```